# Can't overcome System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Zad_8.Chapter11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Cat[] cats = new Cat[10];
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             {
                 cats[i].Name = "Cat " + sequence.NextValue();
             }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cats[i].Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my class in my namespace Chapter11

```
namespace Zad_8.Chapter11
    {
         public class Cat
        {
        private string name = "Cat";
        private string color;

         public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { this.name = value; }
        }

        public Cat(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

and this class also in my namespace Chapter11

```
namespace Zad_8.Chapter11
{
    public class sequence
    {
         private static int current = 0;

         private sequence()
        { }

    public static int NextValue()
       {
        current++;
        return current;
       }
    }
}
```

My goal is to create 10 object - Cat (type) and give them name like CatN, where N is their number.

I have class Cat + name property + get and set.
I have class sequence and it will give me number from 1 to 10

In Main function I want to create array type Cat and with for loop to give on every element in this 10 index array The name CAT + Its number by sequence.

There is no errors in my error List, I tried lots of things like just printing 10 time Cat etc.. but every time it throws me this exception 'System.NullReferenceException.

I read in MSDN but didn't get most of the things good enough to overcome this problem.

I tried by (f11) debugging mode too, and seems like everything is fine but when it starts to read the line with **"cats[i].Name = "Cat " + sequence.NextValue();"** can move on and just stick on it and the compiler can't move on. I saw this in my array any of indexes is null and I'm not sure but it can be the problem.

Can anyone tell me how to do it right ?

I guess it's an annoying and boring question but I'm newbie and have to move through this, so please don't hate this post.

Comment: `Cat` is a `class`, a `class` is a reference type. Reference types initialize with a `null` value. An array of reference types will be an array of `null` values. So for each `Cat`, you need a `new Cat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Cat[] cats = new Cat[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  cats[i].Name = "Cat " + sequence.NextValue();
}
```

to this:

```
Cat[] cats = new Cat[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  cats[i] = new Cat(); //<------This line is new
  cats[i].Name = "Cat " + sequence.NextValue();
}
```

When you create your array it doesn't automatically instantiate (create) new objects.  You need to specifically tell it to do that.

Comment: Thank you for fast answering !

Comment: @StoyanPetkov Be sure to mark the most helpful response as the answer (you may have to wait a few minutes)

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating an array of cats

```
Cat[] cats = new Cat[10];
```

You're just creating an array which can contain cats. But there aren't actually any cats in there unless you put them in.

```
cats[i].Name = "Cat " + sequence.NextValue();
```

Over here you're asking for the 'ith' item in the array - which is null (no cats in there) and trying to do somethign with null. Which is what is causing your problem.

You need to actually put the cat in first.

```
    cats[i] = new Cat("Cat " + sequence.NextValue());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

`cats[i]` is `null` as the object constructor will put the default values in each new slot...which is null for a reference type. You cannot reference `.Name` of a null object

Create your cat object as a whole and plug it in as a whole.

**What your updated code would like like:**

```
cats[i] = new Cat("Cat " + sequence.NextValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Must create your Cat object first. replace your for loop with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     cats[i] = new Cat("Cat " + sequence.NextValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not created an Object cat.
You array is initialized with null values, as Cat is a reference type.

```
Cat[] cats = new Cat[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cats[i] = new Cat("Cat " + sequence.NextValue());
}
```

Comment: I done it, thank you for help :)